# PHP SQL Views counter using PDO prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a variable `$id` which gives me the `id` of the current article and this can help me to make an update query in my database on current article.

This is my code:

```
$vizualizari = $current_views+1;
   $sql1= "UPDATE detalii_cantari SET viz = viz WHERE id = {$id};";
$q1 = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
$q1->execute(array(':viz'=>$vizualizari));
```

I don't get any errors but my code is still not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your correct code is here:

```
$vizualizari = $current_views+1;
    $sql1= "UPDATE detalii_cantari SET viz = :viz WHERE id = {$id}";
$q1 = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
$q1->execute(array(':viz'=>$vizualizari));
```

`;` from the end of sql is not needed here and `viz = viz` must become `viz = :viz` because of PDO.

Comment: In addition, if you're already using PDO to bind your params, you might as well bind $id too.

Comment: Thankyou verry much Domuta Marcel, is what I want, is working now.

Comment: IT IS ALWAYS NECESSARY

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to get rid of the *previous* query and make it in a single statement

```
$sql = "UPDATE detalii_cantari SET viz = viz + 1 WHERE id = ?";
$stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($id));
```

Comment: Yes your SQL Query is simplest way, +1 from me