# voting is still incrementing after post in php

Tags: php, post

I'm working on a early voting system to compare two sets of images.  When you click on the vote button it increments the database by one.  That all works fine, the problem is that if I click on the other vote button the first time, it increments but 1 on the wrong one, and then it works right.

I thought maybe I still had the post set or something, but I put unset post and that didn't fix it.
site is here  http://thereal805productions.com/scratchpad.php
Any ideas?

(here is the original try)

```
if ($_POST) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM image_vote where id = :id ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $image_rand);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    $filename_1 = $row['filename_1'];
    $vote_1 = $row['vote_1'];
    $filename_2 = $row['filename_2'];
    $vote_2 = $row['vote_2'];

    if (isset($_POST['left'])) {
        $vote_1++;  
        unset($_POST['left']);          
    } 

    if (isset($_POST['right'])) { 
        $vote_2++; 
        unset($_POST['right']);
    } 

    $sql = "UPDATE image_vote SET vote_1 =?, vote_2 = ? WHERE id = ? ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($vote_1, $vote_2, $image_rand));
    $done = $stmt->rowCount();

}
```

Then per suggestions I tried:

```
if (isset($_POST['left'])) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM image_vote where id = :id ";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $image_rand);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $vote_1 = $row['vote_1'];

        $vote_1++;  
        echo "<br>I just voted the left";
        $sql = "UPDATE image_vote SET vote_1 =? WHERE id = ? ";
         $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->execute(array($vote_1, $image_rand));
        unset($_POST);  
        // echo "<br> ". var_dump($_POST);  // I get error here $_POST not set      
    } 

if (isset($_POST['right'])) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM image_vote where id = :id ";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $image_rand);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $vote_2 = $row['vote_2'];


        $vote_2++;  
        echo "<br>I just voted the left";
        $sql = "UPDATE image_vote SET vote_2 =? WHERE id = ? ";
         $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->execute(array($vote_2, $image_rand));
        unset($_POST);  
        // echo "<br> ". var_dump($_POST);  // I get error here $_POST not set      
    }
```

Still no luck.

var_dump($_POST) after the unset($_POST) confirms that yes the post is unset.  and the echo statement in the other post doesn't fire, just the increment increases...

Note, I tried disabling the second post all together (say the right one) but still the first time I hit vote, the left will increment.  So somehow it must still be firing...

Upon further reflection...

I don't believe it was incrementing after all, I think it's actually a display issue and the display is just catching up when I hit the post

Basically I think this statement is messing things up.

```
    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['left']) || isset($_POST['right']) ) { 

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM image_vote where id = :id ";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $image_rand);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $vote_1 = $row['vote_1'];
        $vote_2 = $row['vote_2'];

        ?>

        <tr>
            <td>Vote Total = <?php echo $vote_1 ?> </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Vote Total = <?php echo $vote_2 ?> </td>
        </tr> 
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: I suggest you do two seperate queries and put one UPDATE in `if (isset($_POST['left'])) {` and the other inside `if (isset($_POST['right'])) {`. The way you have it now, it's updating and `SET`ting two columns with the same `id`. Maybe even add an `+1` for the columns in the query instead.

Comment: http is stateless an therefore your _POST var cannot be polluted by earlier requests

Comment: "http is stateless an therefore your _POST var cannot be polluted by earlier requests"  i don't understand what this statement means

Comment: It means that your attempt of “un-setting” the POST data is nonsense, because each request has its own set of parameters, and the idea that the POST values from the previous request could have any influence on the current one is just plain wrong.

Comment: Why not keep it simple and do `SET vote_1 = vote_1 +1 WHERE id = ?` and do the same for the other one.  `SET vote_2 = vote_2 +1 WHERE id = ?` @Krone Or see this answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/19476368/

Comment: @CBroe I was thinking the same thing just a few minutes ago actually, about OP unsetting POST, which is doing exactly that after testing OP's test page.

Comment: Your code that show the “Vote Total = …” under each image, where is that?

Answer (score 0):

So after further research my problem was a structural one.  Basically I had my display section of the vote tally separate from my vote portion, and thus when I posted it made it look like the vote was incrementing again instead of the reality which was that the vote display was just updating.

The new code that displays correctly is

```
                    if ($_POST) {

                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM image_vote where id = :id ";
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $image_rand);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $row = $stmt->fetch();
                        $filename_1 = $row['filename_1'];
                        $vote_1 = $row['vote_1'];
                        $filename_2 = $row['filename_2'];
                        $vote_2 = $row['vote_2'];
                        // echo "vote 1 = $vote_1 and vote 2 = $vote_2 <br>";

                        if (isset($_POST['left'])) {
                        $vote_1++;  
                        echo "<br>I just voted the left";
                        $sql = "UPDATE image_vote SET vote_1 =? WHERE id = ? ";
                         $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                         $stmt->execute(array($vote_1, $image_rand));
                        unset($_POST);  
                        // echo "<br> ". var_dump($_POST);  // I get error here $_POST not set      
                        } 

                        if (isset($_POST['right'])) { 
                        $vote_2++; 
                        echo "<br>I just voted the right";
                        $sql = "UPDATE image_vote SET vote_2 =? WHERE id = ? ";
                         $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                         $stmt->execute(array($vote_2, $image_rand));
                        unset($_POST);  
                        // echo "<br> ". var_dump($_POST);  
                        } 


                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM image_vote where id = :id ";
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $image_rand);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $row = $stmt->fetch();
                        $vote_1 = $row['vote_1'];
                        $vote_2 = $row['vote_2'];
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Vote Total = <?php echo $vote_1 ?> </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Vote Total = <?php echo $vote_2 ?> </td>
                        </tr> <?php
                   } 
                        ?>
```

Thanks for all the help, it's very much appreciated.